# jQuery dataTable additional sorting

Tags: sorting, model-view-controller, datatables

I'm using `j_query data_tables` for searching in `M_V_C`, and want to be able to sort the table using my buttons outside the table. and want to sort by profession. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried something yet? Show some code if you have

Answer (score 0):

i have used  Ajax.ActionLink fro my buttons:

```
<pre>

    <div class="personal_types">
        @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">All</button>*@
        @Ajax.ActionLink(
        "All",
        "AllStaff",
        "Staff",
        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" },
                        new { @class = "btn btn-default default" }
    )

        @Ajax.ActionLink(
        "Managers",
        "StaffPosition",
        "Staff",
        new { id = 2 },
        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" },
                new { @class = "btn btn-default default" }
    )
    </div>

<div id="result">


    <div class="manage_list">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="_staff">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="5%">Code</th>
                    <th width="24%">Full Name</th>
                    <th width="15%">Position</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">@item.user_id</th>
                        <td>@item.full_name</td>
                        <td>@item.group_name_geo</td>
                        <td>@item.shop_name</td>
                        <td>@item.reg_date</td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


</div>

</pre>
```